# Telerik controls tabstrip

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

I have a tab strip that contains many tabs. I need to assign an id to my sub-tabs ex. i need to assign id to the tab Demo here. Please help on this

```
 Html.Telerik().TabStrip().Name("Tab1")
       .Items(items =>
       {
           items.Add()
               .Text("Demo").HtmlAttributes(new { onclick = "return  warnOfChanges()" })
               .LoadContentFrom("EDemo", "W2Generation", new {q=Type.Error, cId = Model.C.CId, eId = Model.SelectedE,fYear = Model.Selectedyear });
           items.Add().HtmlAttributes(new { onclick = "return  warnOfChanges()" })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add id as HtmlAttribute.

```
items.Add()
           .Text("Demo").HtmlAttributes(new { onclick = "return  warnOfChanges()", id = "demoTab"})
           .LoadContentFrom("EDemo", "W2Generation", new {q=Type.Error, cId = Model.C.CId, eId = Model.SelectedE,fYear = Model.Selectedyear });
```

Comment: Hmm... It should work. Did you search for this id in html of generated page?